# Sending a javascript object to a server

Tags: javascript, html

My HTML page allows the user to create a list of items that get appended to a table. For simplicity lets say each item has 2 things. 1) a description and 2) a price. I also add this list of items into an object that I want to submit to a server. An example of an object created with 3 items would looks like

```
myObject = {
    "Item1":["description1", "price1"],
    "Item2":["description2", "price2"],
    "Item3":["description3", "price3]
}
```

What is the correct way to submit this data to the server. The only way I am sure of is to append this object to a hidden form. Is there another way.

I am using nodejs with an expressjs framework if that helps. I then input this into a MySQL database by iterating over the object. Thank you.

Comment: Using AJAX comes to mind, also JSON.stringify().

Comment: yes ajax with json should sort you out.

Comment: In case you've never used Ajax, MDN's [Ajax tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) might be helpful.

Comment: O perfect, Ajax it is. I have not used it Yet, thank you for the advice and that guide as well. I appreciate it. All google attempts for best ways of submitting data failed to explain why and when to do what.

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery:

```
var obj = { ... };

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "your/url",
  data: obj
});
```

Comment: The question doesn't mention [tag:jquery].

Comment: To expand on the comment by @Jack, in general, please don't post jQuery answers to non-jQuery questions unless either: 1) jQuery offers functionality (or a plugin) that would be significantly onerous to reproduce with plain JS, or 2) your answer offers a jQuery solution as a supplement or alternative to a non-jQuery solution.

Comment: As you can see above, the question author said he doesn't know AJAX. And this is exactly what I thought, so, I didn't want to complicate my answer by implementing mannualy a JSON Post request, I decided to explain this in the simplest way as possible, using JQuery. I agree (not totally) with you by not suggesting JQuery answers when not explicitly asked. But when the library increase simplicity and the user appears to be a begginner in JS, my opinion is that there's no real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [`JSON.stringify(yourData)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)